# Iterating through a json object and appending each object(Image) to a HTML div tag

Tags: javascript, json, image

My Requirement is : I have a json object which contains some URL(URL is the URL of a image) and their names.I want to iterate through the JSON object and want to get the URL's (nothing but a image) and want to append the image into a div.So that i can see the images from the JSON object.
suppose this is my code

var JSON = [{"name:"A","url":".../a.jpg"},{"name:"B","url":".../b.jpg"},{"name:"C","url":".../c.jpg"}
I want to iterate through this object, get the name and the URL and want to append the name and URl to a div(with some div ID) in my HTML. Detailed code would be helpful.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**A complete example :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var jsonData = [{"name":"A","url":".../a.jpg"},{"name":"B","url":".../b.jpg"},{"name":"C","url":".../c.jpg"}];
                var imgContainer = $("#imgContainer");
                $.each(jsonData,function(key,value){
                    console.log(imgContainer);
                    imgContainer.append('<img title="'+value.name+'" src="'+value.url+'" />');
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="imgContainer"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{name:"A",url:".../a.jpg"},{name:"B",url:".../b.jpg"},{name:"C",url:".../c.jpg"}];
var div = document.getElementById("#id");
data.forEach(function(item, index){
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ("Name:" + item.name + " URL:" + item.url + "<br>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Rajesh CP

```
function test() {
    var JSON = [{ name: "A", url: "http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg" }, { name: "B", url: "http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg" }, { name: "C", url: "http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg" }];
    var element = $("#divID");
    $(myArray).each(function (key) {
        html = '';
        html += '<div class="example_result notranslate" style="text-align:center">\n'
        html += '\t<h2>' + JSON[key].name + '</h2>\n';
        html += '\t<img src="' + JSON[jey].url + '">\n';
        html += '</div>\n';
        html += '<br>\n';
        element.append(html);
    });
}
```

Comment: But for this simple thing do we need to include JQuery lib ? Correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: This is appreciable help but i need to iterate through the JSON object(having 3 records as in example above) create an "li" for each record(so total 3 li will be created) and append each "name" and "url" for the specific li and finally the whole li has to be appended to the HTML of the div.