# how use a local JSON object as data source for select2.js version 4.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I am using select2.js VERSION 4.0 for displaying a nice dropdown with flags:

Html :

```
 <select style="width: 300px">
                <optgroup label="Europe">
                    <option value="cz" > Tcheque</option>
                    <option value="al" > Albania</option>
                    <option value="mt" >   Malte</option>
                    <option value="mc" > Monaco</option>
                    <option value="ro" > Romania</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Africa">
                    <option value="dz">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="ml">Mali</option> 
                    <option value="ma">Marocco</option>   
                </optgroup>

      </select>
```

Javascript:

```
 function formatResult(item) {
              if(!item.id) {
                // return `text` for optgroup
                return item.text;
              }
            // return item template
          var my_class = "flag flag-" + item.id;
          return '<i>' + item.text + ' <img src="~/Content/images/blank.gif" class="' + my_class + '" alt="dzdz" /></i>';
        }

        function formatSelection(item) {
          // return selection template
          return '<b>' + item.text + '</b>';
        }

        $('select').select2({

          formatResult: formatResult,

          formatSelection: formatSelection
        });
```

It renders what I want :

[image]

But I want to do that with local source with javascript data like that:

```
var datasource =     [
       {"id":"cz","text":"Tcheque"},
       {"id":"al","text":"Albania"},
       {"id":"mt","text":"Malte"},
       {"id":"mc","text":"Monaco"},
       {"id":"ro","text":"Romania"}
    ]

$('select').select2({
            data:datasource ,
            formatResult: formatResult,
            formatSelection: formatSelection
          });
```

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: this question shows you how to loop and append http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703168/iterating-through-a-json-object-and-appending-each-objectimage-to-a-html-div-t

Comment: this question is not duplicate, link is for old version that doesn't work in same way